# Knockout Validation - have input validate some other field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using [knockout validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) and trying to accomplish what should be a simple use case.

I want an input to be bound to a certain field, but validate a different one.  Something like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="validationElement: referrerId, value: referrerName" />
```

But it seems to always (**correctly**) show validation errors for `referrerName` instead of `referrerId`.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Basically I want this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3pQt/1/

to show an error for referrerId (which in the fiddle is always empty).

Comment: So in your example which property is invalid: referrerId or referrerName? And when you are talking about "validation errors" do you mean the automatically inserted validation messages? Can you put together a jsfiddle which showcases your use case?

Comment: `do you mean the automatically inserted validation messages` - yes.  I want this text box to validate referrerId.  That's it.  I want the tb to keep its value bound to referrerName, and validate against referrerId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/W3pQt/3/

I made a custom validator, because I couldn't figure out how to do it without one.

```
ko.validation.rules['dependsOn'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        return typeof otherVal() !== "undefined";
    },
    message: 'Referrer Id must have a value: {0}'
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

...

```
this.referrerName.extend({ dependsOn: this.referrerId });
```

Don't get hung up on the name 'dependsOn' which is dumb. Naming things is hard.

Comment: `Don't get hung up on the name 'dependsOn' which is dumb. Naming things is hard.` - glad I'm not the only one who thinks that :)

Comment: If you have the time and inclination to look at another.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103748/pass-computed-or-observable-into-knockout-validator

Comment: Sorry about that - I was so frustrated with ko validate that I didn't really think that second question through.  Thanks again for your help here.

Comment: Hey, no problem. I've been there. Glad to help!